# Exp:resso Store: Setting discount expiry date / time - Store v2

Tags: expresso-store, discounts

On Expresso Store v2 you have the option to set an expiry date for a promo / discount code. Unfortunately, whilst the setting represents a date and time the Javascript picker only lets you select the date - it automatically selects the current time. Attempting to manually edit the time in the text field doesn't work.

[image]

As the discount code did expire on the precise time (not just date) that was selected its probably important to allow people to edit the time too!

Thanks

T

Comment: Just following up on this - we have a fix coming soon in v2.0.4

Comment: Great news, thanks Adrian, do you have a date for the 2.0.4 release please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed in [Store 2.0.4](https://exp-resso.com/docs/release_notes.html#store_204) which was released today:

> Fixed ability to edit time manually in datetime fields in the control panel

You can now manually edit the time after selecting the date you need.